# proc_open(): pty pseudo terminal not supported on this system Cent OS6

Tags: terminal, centos, communication, php

I tried to use pty terminal type with PHP `proc_open()` function but could not success and got following message:

> PHP Warning: proc_open(): pty pseudo terminal not supported on this system in xxxx.php on line xx

I saw PHP forums and it was raised somewhere in 2006 with [Bug #39224](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39224) but not sure why it was not fixed.

If you can give any clue why it was not fixed? Any security or any other issue? I can see this code is still available in `proc_open.c`. I'm using PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.

Comment: Where did you obtain PHP packages from? According to the bug-report this is related to the PHP configure script.

Comment: Installation was taken from php.net/downloads.php‎. If you will see proc_open.c where actual implementation of PHP proc_open() function lies, it is commented using #if 0 &.....